# Kotlin static constant field returning modified String value

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-reflect, kotlin-companion

I'm trying to reach a constant String value of the Class name. But I really don't understand why I get a modified String value. 
Here is the code that I'm working on:

```
class TestClass {
    companion object {
            @JvmField
            val TAG1: String = this::class.java.name as String
            val TAG2: String = this::javaClass.name 
    } 
}
```

In another class trying to reach the value like this:

```
class ComboClass {
    override fun onStart() {
       val tag1 = TestClass.TAG1
       val tag2 = TestClass.TAG2

       // tag1 "packagePath.TestClass$Companion"
       // tag2 "packagePath.TestClass$Companion"
    }
}
```

Why Am I getting `packagePath.TestClass$Companion` at the end of the String value? I'm expecting to get `packagePath.TestClass`

Thanks

Comment: Because `this` is the companion object of the class TestClass. It's not an instance of TestClass. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#companion-objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Why Am I getting packagePath.TestClass$Companion at the end of the String value?

Companion objects have classes of their own, in this case the object is of type `TestClass$Companion`, so `this::class.java.name as String` and `this::javaClass.name` both give you the name of the companion object's class.

## How to get TestClass

You will want to use `TestClass::class.java.name` and `TestClass::javaClass.name` instead to get `TestClass`